# Checking if a string is found in one of multiple columns in mySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to check if a string is found in one or more columns.

Basically, I have a program which lets you checks multiple fields (name, surname, etc...)

If both name and surname are checked and the user enters just the name, for example chris it would be easy to check it in mySQL with the LIKE parameter like this:

```
select * from tblClients WHERE name LIKE '%john%';
```

This obviously works. However, what I need to do is that if both name and surname are checked it would do something like this:

```
select * from tblClients WHERE (name or surname) LIKE '%john%';
```

I want that if this logic is made when there is a client named john doe, the second command will still find that client.

I tried this command and no syntax errors were found, however, 0 results where returned.

Any suggesstions please?

Comment: What output do you get if you run `select *, (name or surname) as my_magic_col from tblClient`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can't you just use separate WHERE clauses, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM tblClients
WHERE (name LIKE '%john%')
OR (surname LIKE '%john%')
```

You're having to amend the SQL based on which columns the user selects anyway.

Comment: Like davethegr8's solution, but the parentheses are optional.

Comment: +1.  Not sure why the other solution using dynamic SQL is getting voted up.  Dynamic SQL should be avoided.

Comment: This should be also the most efficient solution because it avoids concatenation (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77378682/2314737)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do this:, as SQL will choke on the (name or surname) part

```
select * from tblClients WHERE name LIKE '%john%' or surname LIKE '%john%';
```

I'm not sure what language your using, but in psuedocode, you can make this a little easier with a simple function

```
query = [whatever you are searching for]
var columns = array('name', 'surname')
var where = array
foreach columns as column
    where[] = column + ' like "%' + query + '%"'

sql = "select * from tblClients WHERE " + join(where, ' OR ');

//where join joins values of an array into a string
```

Comment: I know I tried that and it works. However I have this line of code:

    $sql .= " from $table where name LIKE '%" . $query ."%' " 

and it is not allowing me to create a foreach loop inside there for some reason...

How can I go around this?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having separate LIKE-clauses, you can concatenate the columns:

```
select * 
from tblClients 
WHERE name || surname LIKE '%john%'
```

This leaves some edge case (name = 'jo' and surname = 'hn' would be a match), if you're concerned about this you can add a separator between the columns

```
WHERE name || ' ' || surname LIKE '%john%'
```

I'm not sure about the performance impact of the two choices, but a LIKE with a percent at the start and the end will not use an index, so I don't think there will be problems.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using UNIONs over ORs - ORs are notorious for poor performance, and risk maintenance issues if not properly understood:

```
SELECT c.* FROM tblClients c WHERE c.name LIKE '%john%'
UNION
SELECT c.* FROM tblClients c WHERE c.surname LIKE '%john%'
```

Keep in mind that `UNION` will return a distinct list - duplicates will be removed, but it will perform slower than using `UNION ALL` (which will **not** remove duplicates).  Use what suits your purpose

Comment: Also be aware that using `LIKE '%` will not use an index.

Answer (score 1):

This example column NAME and SURNAME one query, 1 space middle.

```
    $Sql="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CONCAT(NAME,' ',SURNAME) LIKE '%".$query."%' ";

//NAME = İSA
//SURNAME = ABC
//Query = İSA ABC
```

one query find.
[image: mysql 2 columt 1 query]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to program it.

Here is what I did:

```
$like = "";

foreach ($fields as $field)
{
    if ($like == "")
    {
        $like = $field . " LIKE '%" . $query . "%' or ";
    }
    else
    {
        $like = $like . $field . " LIKE '%" . $query . "%' or ";
    }
}

$like = substr_replace($like, "", -3);
```

This way, all ORs where insterted in a for loop and appended to a string. Then I programmed the SQL string like this:

```
$sql  = "select * ";
$sql .= " from $table where  " . $like
```

Hope this helps somebody else :)

Thanks for your posts.

Comment: The test `if ($like == "")` is not necessary.

Comment: If you are satisfied then you should pick the nearest correct answer.