# Mysql - how to use like on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-like

I've searched in mysql query a word in multiple column in java program. The number of column is variable.
It is correct this query:

```
select * from customer with (city, name) like%'adelaide'%
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a string is found in one of multiple columns in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804469/checking-if-a-string-is-found-in-one-of-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Answer (score 24):

You can use CONCAT() function:

```
select * from customer WHERE concat(city,name) like '%adelaide%'
```

You can add as many columns to the concat function as you like.
Also as you see I changed your like syntax, '%WORD%' and used a simple where clause.

Comment: For this to work correctly you have to be sure that there no case when columns don't contain "adelaide" in them but the concatenated string does. E.g. for column1 = 'Paradela' and column2 = 'idea'.

Comment: You're right, but it can be solved by tweeking it, for example concatenating a unique character between the two columns @cl0ne

Answer (score 9):

It's better to use `CONCAT_WS()` function.

`CONCAT()` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`.

`CONCAT_WS()` skip any `NULL` values after the separator argument.

Answer (score 1):

multiple like statements can not be used with or directly. You have to use column name for each like statement.

Use multiple like as mentioned below.

```
Select * 
from animals 
where 
(
[animalscolumn] like ('%dog%') or 
[animalscolumn] like ('%cat%') or 
[animalscolumn] like ('%gerbil%') or 
[animalscolumn] like ('%hamster%') or 
[animalscolumn] like ('%guinea pig%')
)
```

Comment: much  better using CONCAT. Using OR will not work when the search query spans multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from customer with city like%'adelaide'% or name like%'adelaide'%
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it answer to the question ?