# SQL WHERE statement multiple columns LIKE one value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Trying to get a SQL query where you define the value once and it searches multiple columns. I got this working for the equal operator, but I need this for a LIKE operator as well. This is were the problem is.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.ref_id
WHERE (table1.email, table2.email) LIKE '%example@example.com%'
```

This is my current query which is not working. Looked at a few other questions online, but those solutions didn't work for me.

How can I search multiple columns for one value with a LIKE operator?

Comment: Are you doing something with parameters that only allows the pattern to appear once in the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific answer to your question is something like this:

```
WHERE CONCAT_WS('|', table1.email, table2.email) LIKE '%example@example.com%'
```

That would generally not be used.  The more common approach is simply:

```
WHERE table1.email LIKE '%example@example.com%' OR
      table2.email LIKE '%example@example.com%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.ref_id
WHERE 
table1.email LIKE '%example@example.com%'
OR
table2.email LIKE '%example@example.com%'
```

This should be faster in general than other solutions using concatenations of different columns (with `+`, `concat`, `CONCAT_WS`, etc.) because of the overhead of running the concatenation for each row.

See also: [Query performance with concatenation and LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29599330/2314737).