# Check if string is found in one of multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-like

I want to search a string in multiple columns to check if it exists in any.
I found a solution for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804469/checking-if-a-string-is-found-in-one-of-multiple-columns-in-mysql)
The answer by [Thorsten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25320/thorsten) is short but that is a solution for mysql server not for SQL Server.
So I would like to apply similar query in SQL Server.
Here is the query suggested by Thorsten.

```
Select * 
from tblClients 
WHERE name || surname LIKE '%john%'
```

I tried it as

```
/* This returns nothing */
Select * 
from Items 
Where ISNULL(Code, '') + ISNULL(Code1, '') = '6922896068701';
Go

/* This generate error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '|'. 
I also used this one in mysql but it does not show the exact match.
*/
Select * 
from Items 
WHERE Code || Code1 = '6922896068701';
Go

/* This generate error Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Or'. */
Select * 
from Items 
WHERE Code Or Code1 = '6922896068701';
Go
```

Is it really possible in SQL Server?
Note: The answer by [J__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20315/j) works accurately in the upper Question link but I want the comparison string to be entered once for all columns where I look for it like Thorsten.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @Habib `WHERE name || surname LIKE '%john%'` is  a very, *very*, **very** bad solution both for MySQL and SQL Server, as the server can't use of any indexes to accelerate the query. If you have a table with 50K rows, the server will have to search every single one of them.

Comment: @Habib in *both* databases, the real solution for substring searches is to create a full-text search index and use it. It's not as easy as the "solution" but it's orders of magnitude faster. In your case though you don't need any tricks as you aren't searching substrings

Comment: BTW out of all the answers in that question, the one you picked is simply wrong and can't handle NULLs in MySQL either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I think that separate logical checks in the `WHERE` clause for each column is the way to go here.  If you *can't* do that for some reason, consider using a `WHERE IN (...)` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Items
WHERE '6922896068701' IN (Code, Code1);
```

If instead you want `LIKE` logic, then it gets tricky.  If you knew that the matching codes would always consist of numbers/letters, then you could try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Items
WHERE ',' + Code + ',' + Code1 + ',' LIKE '%,6922896068701,%';
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing the two comparisons separately:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%john%' OR
      surname LIKE '%john%'
```

Unless you specifically want to find times when the names are combined, such as "Maryjoh" "Needlebaum" or whatever.

It is generally better to focus on one column at a time, because that helps the optimizer.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using comparison separately? I don't see any disadvantage of using the comparison by where in clause and the advantage in my opinion is that it will reduce LOC for me.

Comment: @Habib One issue here is that of making your `WHERE` clause _sargable_, which means making it possible for the database to use an index.  When you try to search for a matching name inside a concatenated string using wildcards, immediately an index cannot be used.  So it is better to try to compare with equality using separate terms in the `WHERE` clause, if possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for pointing the issue. Using separate terms isn't an issue and I will definitely use it separate after this comment of your. Currently is I don't need to use anything  using the query just trying to find out if the string exists.

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL  this may work;

```
 Select * 
 from Items 
 WHERE Code = '6922896068701' Or Code1 = '6922896068701'
```

Comment: I think you didn't visited the link above it's already mentioned in that link. Still thanks.